# Count page views laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, laravel

How to count page views. Each time a save to the database. please. I'm using laravel 5.2.
I tried several packages but could not?

Comment: Why not just use Google Analytics? No database or extra code necessary.

Comment: Each time a page is loaded you increment a counter? That doesn't sound very useful. Someone can just sit there and refresh a page for hours to mess with your stats.

Comment: You say you've tried some solutions but do not talk about them here. It is much more helpful and collaborative to ask for help about the problems you have than to ask for a solution. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You can create a table that stores all view records, so you can count the views, including filtering by session, ip, etc.

First, create the table:

```
Schema::create("browsing_history", function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";

            $table->increments("id");
            $table->string("url");
            $table->string("session_id");
            $table->string("user_id");
            $table->string("ip");
            $table->string("agent");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Second, create the corresponding model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class BrowsingHistory extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'browsing_history';

    public static function createLog() {
            $browsingHistory = new BrowsingHistory();
            $browsingHistory->url = \Request::url();
            $browsingHistory->session_id = \Request::getSession()->getId();
            $browsingHistory->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
            $browsingHistory->ip = \Request::getClientIp();
            $browsingHistory->agent = \Request::header('User-Agent');
            $browsingHistory->save();
    }

}
```

Third, add the call to the log by overwriting the builder of your views controllers:

```
public function __construct()
{
    BrowsingHistory::createLog();
}
```

To query the count, ignoring hits by the same session:

```
public function countViewsPerSession($url)
{
    return BrowsingHistory::where("url", $url)
        ->groupBy("session_id")
        ->count();
}
```

Comment: Each time F5 it increases to a value, there is no way to set a certain amount of time, it is newly increased

Comment: @QUANGMAIVAN - And what have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add a database column for views and increment it every time you load the page for a user. Then, you can separate unique views by the IP address or user making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jean_Macros I was able to solve the problem with a twist

I advise anyone to follow @Jean_Macros code for details but to

To stop the page from increment per reload then do the below

here you go:

put this code in your model

```
protected $table = 'page_view_counts';

public static function createLog($page_owner_id) {
    $browser = new BrowserDetection(); //just a function i wrote
    // special values
    $address = getRealIp(); //just a function i wrote
    $browser = $browser->getName()." ver-".$browser->getVersion();
    $url = Request::url();
    $session_id = Request::getSession()->getId();
    $log_exists = (new PageViewCount)->where([['page_id', '=', $page_owner_id], ['session_id', '=', $session_id], ['url', '=', $url]])->exists();
        if (!$log_exists) {
            $pageViewCount = new DiaryViewCount();
            $pageViewCount->url = $url;
            $pageViewCount->session_id = $session_id;
            $pageViewCount->diary_id = $page_owner_id;
            $pageViewCount->address = $address;
            $pageViewCount->browser = $browser;
            $pageViewCount->save();
        }
}
```